# Keras Sequence to Sequence Prediction, issues with shapes

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I'm trying to do sequence to sequence learning with Keras. My data looks like the following.

```
h h h l l l   i r
h h l l l l   i r
h l l l l l   i r
h m h m h h   c u
...
```

What I've done is to one-hot encode the `X`'s and `y`'s so my data gets transformed as follows

```
[[1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 ... 
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]]
```

and my `y`'s look like

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
...
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]
```

The function that does the one-hot encoding for the training set is the following

```
def one_hot_encode_xy(seq_x, seq_y, n_uniq_x, n_uniq_y):
 encoding_x = list()
 encoding_y = list()
 nsize_x = len(n_uniq_x)
 nsize_y = len(n_uniq_y)
 for val in seq_x:
     vector = [0 for _ in xrange(nsize_x)]
     index = n_uniq_x.index(val)
     vector[index] = 1
     encoding_x += vector

 for val in seq_y:
     vector = [0 for _ in xrange(nsize_y)]
     index = n_uniq_y.index(val)
     vector[index] = 1
     encoding_y += vector
 X0 = array(encoding_x)
 y0 = array(encoding_y)
 return X0, y0
```

The part that I'm stuck on is I keep getting shape incompatibility errors when I try to fit the model `X` and `y`s. The model I'm using is the following

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(150, input_shape=(1, 18)))
model.add(RepeatVector(1))
model.add(LSTM(150, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(18, activation='softmax')))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=100, verbose=2)
```

How should I reshape my `X`'s `y`'s and/or the model so that I can do a simple seq2seq learning on this? Can someone help out please? Any help appreciated.

An example of the error I'm getting is the following

> ```
> model.fit(X, y, epochs=100, verbose=2)
> ```
>
> File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keras/engine/training.py", line 958, in fit
>      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keras/engine/training.py", line 757, in _standardize_user_data
>     File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 128, in standardize_input_data
>   ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (18, 18)

This is how I initialize my `X`, `y` and `X_test`. I've a toy data set of 18 rows (as shown above) and want to test it on 2 cases.

```
X = np.zeros((18, 18), dtype='float32')
y = np.zeros((18, 18), dtype='float32')
X_test = np.zeros((2, 18), dtype='float32')
```

Comment: Can you show the error ?, you just need to change the shape passed and output dense as of my view.

Comment: @NagaKiran added the error I'm getting

Answer (score 0):

the Train input shape should be 3 dimensions (Samples,Timesteps,Features)

```
**Samples**. One sequence is one sample. A batch is comprised of one or more samples.
**Time Steps**. One time step is one point of observation in the sample.
**Features**. One feature is one observation at a time step.
```

In your case the input data , if you dont have many features just add one more dimension to input data or you can use look back to create short term variations of sequence, it will work

```
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0],X.shape[1],1)
y = y.reshape(y.shape[0],1,y.shape[1])
```

While giving input shape give X[0].shape as input
.   [example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/)

Comment: The said approach does not work. I get the same error.

Comment: @broccoli Same reshaping should happen to y also. I have tried its working y = y.reshape(y.shape[0],1,y.shape[1])